# Sequence vs max primary key value + 1

Tags: oracle

When inserting a new record in a table, there can be two approaches, one is to find the max value of primary key column and adding 1 to it or use a sequence. Which approach is better and why?

What is the impact if we find the next primary key value by incrementing the max value of the primary key column in a table having less than 20,000 records?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Try the max value approach in a multiple user environment and you will find out why using a sequence is the correct method.

Comment: I suggest you use the sequence. The cost of do nextval will always lower than doing a max operation

Comment: serialization (locking causing waiting) certainly is demerit to the max primary key + 1 approach.

Comment: A third option is to use sys_guid()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: difference between max(id)+1 and sequence.nextval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210835/oracle-difference-between-maxid1-and-sequence-nextval)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Q: Which approach is better and why?**

**A:** Using a `SEQUENCE` object is a better approach.

The `MAX(id)+1` approach to obtaining a *unique* id value is *broken* in a multi threaded environment, absent concurrency killing locking. This problem will not be exposed in single user testing; but it's very easy to demonstrate this using two different sessions. Consider this sequence of operations:

session 1: `SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS next_id FROM mytable`  --> 42

session 2: `SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS next_id FROM mytable`  --> 42

session 1: `INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (42)`

session 2: `INSERT INTO mytable (id) VALUES (42)`

To prevent two (or more) separate sessions from returning the same `next_id` value, it would be necessary for a session to obtain an exclusive lock on the table before it executed the query. It would also need to hold that lock, until after a row with that `next_id` value was inserted to the table, before releasing the lock. While that session holds the exclusive lock on the table, no other session can query or insert into the table, other sessions will block if they attempt to. (We don't want to kill database performance by introducing this kind of locking, that's not the right approach, so we're not going to demonstrate how that would be done.)

Oracle provides the `SEQUENCE` object as an efficient means for obtaining a unique value, and queries against SEQUENCE objects are "safe" in a multi-threaded environment. For performance under a high load, we'd increase the "cache" value of the sequence, the number of values that are available in memory, so we can satisfy more NEXTVAL requests without requiring a write to the redo log.

Given those two options, the `SEQUENCE` is the better approach.

---

**Q: What is the impact if we find the next primary key value by incrementing the max value of the primary key column in a table having less than 20,000 records?**

**A:** A query that retrieves the maximum value of an indexed column (a column that is the leading column in an index), and adding one to it, should be very efficient, as long as the session is able to obtain the required share lock (that is, the session isn't blocked by an exclusive lock.)