# ASP.NET MVC 3 application with existing oracle database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, unique-constraint, ado.net-entity-data-model

I generated my model from the database using an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  I then created a controller based on the model and then created a view from the controller.

The application will return the contents of the database, however, when I attempt to create a new record, I receive a "unique constraint" message.

I cannot create a sequence on the table and the DBA is not going to either.  I can create a view which will return the MAX(ID) + 1.

How can I feed the results of the view into the function doing the add so I can insert the record?

Comment: So the primary key is a single number column? What reason does the DBA give for not using a sequence?

Comment: Also, `MAX(ID)+1` is almost certainly a very, very bad idea. At best it's just a bad idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210835/oracle-difference-between-maxid1-and-sequence-nextval

Comment: What about using a GUID as an ID? - It would be better that MAX(ID) + 1, which I'm pretty sure turns out to be not thread safe